# How to route to a MAC address on a specific interface on macOS?

Tags: networking, macos, routing

I have a device with mac address `a2:a0:f1:7c:7f:36` on interface `en8`:

```
en8: flags=8b63<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6467<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether a2:a0:f1:7c:7f:36 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
```

I would like to provide internet access to this device by assigning `172.31.1.2/24` as the NAT interface address while also running a DNS server on my macbook.

This is the command I tried to set up the NAT:

```
sudo route -nv add -host 172.31.1.2/24 -link a2:a0:f1:7c:7f:36 -iface en8
```

However the entry that appears in the routing table (`netstat -rn -f inet`) is:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
172.31.1.2         a0:f1:7c:7f:36     UHLS              en0
```

Somehow the `Gateway` shows up with the first 2 hex digits truncated, and the interface is `en0` instead of `en8`. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: I've also tried

```
sudo route -nv add -net 172.31.1.2/24 -iface -link a2:a0:f1:7c:7f:36
```

Which resulted in

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
172.31.1/24        link#6             UCSc              en0      !
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that `en8` has no IP address - possibley because of problem #2.

Your second problem is that `en8` is `inactive` and no cable is plugged in (the cable type would be specified after the media).

It will NEVER send an IP packet

For a valid interface I'd expect to see something like:

```
en6: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6467<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether 48:65:ee:1e:e5:3b
    inet6 fe80::cb7:42bb:c887:1232%en6 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xf
    inet 192.168.1.95 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (**1000baseT <full-duplex>**)
    status: **active**
```

So your first step would be to plug an active cable into `en8` - whatever that is.  (You didn't tell us.). Or attach to a WiFi network if it is a WiFi interface.

Next, find en8 in `Apple > System Preferences ... > Network` but you'll need to know which physical interface it is, then assign it the 172.31.1.2/24 address you desire.

Then, go back to `Apple > System Preferences ... > Sharing` and check the `[x] Internet Sharing` option - select your from and to connections there - [although I have this sneaking suspicion that Apple may re-assign the IP]

Anyway - hopefully enough to get you started.  Tweaking the sharing to make the shared network use your local DNS server may be a bit more challenging.  Perhaps you could tell us a bit more about the end game and why you want to do your own DNS and sharing.

Comment: macOS will add 255 to the subnet using sharing, ie 192.168.0.0/24 becomes 192.168.1.0/24. After that it should be pretty much plug & play, DHCP & DNS will set up automatically. [You can fiddle with it afterwards, but I've never seen the point.]